# Accept 'DD MM YYYY' or 'DD MMM YYYY' at same time in ngx-Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, ngx-bootstrap

**In ngx-Bootstrap datepicker**

1. Currently the input only accepts 'DD MMM YYY' or 'MM DD YYYY' at same time.
2. If I give input like 30 10 1995 the it gives an error. Invalid format
3. how to achieve the 'DD/MM/YYYY' or 'DD MMM YYYY' accept input format at same time

---

- ngx-Bootstrap: 1.9.3
- Angular version: 4

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, the config value `dateInputFormat` looks like it only handles a string.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/datepicker/bs-datepicker.config.ts

The `dateInputFormat` is used in two places: 1. to parse and 2. to format.

For just parsing, you can get away with setting the `dateInputFormat` to an array, because the parser accepts either a string or an array.

```
**NOT A SOLUTION**
[bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: [ 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ] }"
```

But then this causes errors when it comes to formatting the date for display in the input, as the formatter only accepts a string. This makes sense when you think about it, as the formatter would have to guess at which formatter you wanted to use, and there is potential for ambiguity between formats.

So as far as I can tell, it's not possible through the config.

Handling events via the `(bsValueChange)` event is also not possible, as it only fires when a "valid" date is found.

I think the requirement for multiple formats is a valid feature request. The spec would be something like

> `dateInputFormat` accepts either a string or a string array. If a string, that format is used for both parsing and formatting. If an array, the first successful match is used for parsing. The first string is used for formatting.

Comment: Your spec can't work. There are many, many strings that match both the OP formats, so some may be treated as d/m/y and others as m/d/y. If only the first used for formatting, what about the strings that matched the second format?

Comment: @kurt-hamilton is there any possibilities to change 'dateInputFormat' based on user input (keypress)?
I tried this approach but the result was not expected.

Comment: @SahilRalkar Without going through even source code, I don't know what possibilities you have. I don't see why you couldn't, as long as you destroy and recreate the control with the new config.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I raised this task on ngx-bootstrap git profile

Comment: @SahilRalkar stuck on a similar issue, did you find any workaround ?

Comment: If you are working on older version library then upgrade ti latest one and try